# Can someone create speech-recognition tag?

Tags: support

It seems that all posts related to speech recognition are tagged as "audio" which is inaccurate or at least incomplete. I believe this happens because nobody interested in this issue has the required reputation to create the new tag.

Is there a member of the community with the required reputation that could create a **"speech-recognition"** tag so we can tag our questions better? I'm asking this because I see many questions regarding this topic, and the very popular library CMU PocketSphinx has published [instructions to build their library specifically for the raspberry pi](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/raspberrypi). Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go :)

[speech-recognition](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/speech-recognition)

Happy tagging!

Comment: Thanks! Let the tagging begin :P